# Rudin's "Functional Analysis" theorem 6.5

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

In the proof of part (a) of theorem 6.5 (pg. 139 of the first edition) he states that:

Since $\mathcal{D}_k\cap W$ is open in $\mathcal{D}_k$, we have proved that $\mathcal{D}_k\cap V \in \tau_k$

Why is that true? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide some context, $\mathscr{D}_K$ is the $C^\infty$ functions with support in $K\subset \Omega$, $K$ being compact.  They have a topology $\tau_K$ given by seminorms.  There is also a topology $\tau$ for $\mathscr{D}$, and we have an arbitrarily chosen $V\in \tau$ by hypothesis.  We have also by hypothesis an arbitrarily chosen $\phi\in \mathscr{D}_K\cap V$. We are told in the proof that by Theorem 6.4 we can find $W$ which satisfies $\phi+W\subset V$ and is convex, balanced, and satisfies $\mathscr{D}_K \cap W\in\tau_K$.

We want to infer that $\mathscr{D}_K \cap V\in\tau_K$, i.e., that $\mathscr{D}_K\cap V$ is open in the topology $\tau_K$.  That inference can be made because $\phi$ was an arbitrary element in $\mathscr{D}_K\cap V$, and we have a $\tau_K$-neighborhood (i.e., neighborhood in the topology $\tau_K$) surrounding $\phi$ and contained in $\mathscr{D}_K\cap V$, that $\tau_K$-neighborhood being $\phi+(\mathscr{D}_K \cap W)$.  The fact that the latter is contained in $\mathscr{D}_K\cap V$ follows from $\phi+W\subset V$.  The general principle being applied is that, if every point of a set contains a neighborhood which lies within that set, then the set is open.

I think I've just paraphrased Rudin.

Comment: Could you explain the last statement: "...if every point of a set contains a neighborhood which lies within that set, then the set is open." It's not clear to me why that's true. Thanks.

Comment: The set will be the union of those neighborhoods, since every member of the set has one of those neighborhoods.  The union of open sets is open by definition of topology.  (In my statement I was assuming the usual definition of neighborhood, namely a set $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ if it contains $x$ and is open.)